# how to evaluate hypertension condition on textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to produce the following results

- systolic greater than 120 & diastolic less than 80  = Normal
- systolic greater than 119 to systolic less than 130 & diastolic less than 80  = Elevated
- systolic greater than 129 to systolic less than 140 & diastolic greater than 79 to diastolic less than 90 =
  Higher BP Stage 1
- systolic greater than139 to systolic less than 180 & diastolic greater than 89 to diastolic less than 120
  = Higher BP Stage 2
- systolic greater than 139 to systolic less than 180 & diastolic greater than 89 to diastolic less than 120
  = Higher BP Stage 2
- systolic greater than 180 & diastolic greater than 120  = Hypertensive Crisis!!!! .

The HTML and JavaScript code is :

```js
function bpcal() {
  var bp = document.admin.bp.value;
  var bpm = document.admin.bpm.value;
  
  if (bp > 0 && bpm > 0) {
    var bpva = bpm / bp;
    document.admin.bpval.value = bpva;
    
    if (bpm < 120 && bp < 80) {
      document.admin.bpmeaning.value = "Normal.";
      document.admin.bpmeaning.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";
    }
    
    if (bpm > 119 && bpm < 130 && bp < 80) {
      document.admin.bpmeaning.value = "Elevated.";
      document.admin.bpmeaning.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    
    if (bpm > 129 && bpm < 140 && bp > 79 && bp < 90) {
      document.admin.bpmeaning.value = "Higher BP Stage 1.";
      document.admin.bpmeaning.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
    
    if (bpm > 139 && bpm < 180 && bp > 89 && bp < 120) {
      document.admin.bpmeaning.value = "Higher BP Stage 2.";
      document.admin.bpmeaning.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
    }
    
    if (bpm > 180 && bp > 120) {
      document.admin.bpmeaning.value = "Hypertensive Crisis!!!! .";
      document.admin.bpmeaning.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form role="form" name="admin" method="post">

  <section>
    <div style="float:left;margin-right:2px;">
      <label for="name">BP Systolic U-#</label>
      <input type='text' name="bpm" id="bpm" size="10" required="true" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-right:2px;">
      <label for="Weight">BP Diastolic L-#</label>
      <input type='text' name="bp" id="bp" size="10" required="true" value="" onkeyup="bpcal()" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;margin-right:2px;">
      <label for="BpV">BPVal</label>
      <input readonly type='text' size="10" name="bpval" />
    </div>

    <div style="float:left;">
      <label for="st">Status</label>
      <input type='text' readonly type='text' name='bpmeaning' size="30" /></td>

    </div>
</Form>
```

My code works only up to elevated results - other conditions are not working.

when I input any systolic value below 120 and diastolic below 80 I get "normal'.

When I input systolic value between 120 & 129 and diastolic below 80 I get "elevated.

But when I input systolic value between 130 & 139 and diastolic between 80 & 89 i do not get any result.

I hope it's clear now - the code works when systolic values are below 130 and diastolic value is not between values.

How best can I do this?

Comment: Why is tagged php but javascript is posted?

Comment: i thought i added JavaScript as well

Comment: And why php? Do you need the php code? Is something wrong with your js code? It is unclear what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Be more specific. Give an example of supplied input values and expected results, and the results you get now

Comment: when i input any systolic value below 120 and diastolic below 80 i get "normal'  when i input systolic value between 120 & 129 and diastolic below 80 i get "elevated but when i input systolic value between 130 & 139 and diastolic between  80 & 89 i do not get any result. i hope its clear now  so the code works when systolic value are below 130 and  diastolic value is not between values

Comment: I just made your code into a runnable demo. I entered 130 and 85, and got "Higher BP Stage 1." as the result. It's not clear why you think there's a problem with that. You can run it yourself right here in the question and see what I mean.

Comment: ADyson thanks, a lot, the problem was that when i changed the values it wasn't refreshing the results but now its working

Comment: No worries. You should probably put the keyup event on both textboxes, then it will re-calculate whenever you change either of them, that will help.